# How to Display Teams posts on SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-teams, powerapps-forms

I have a customer request to see if there's a way to display a specific Teams group's Posts on a SharePoint (communication site) page.  I've explored Viva Connections a bit, but that doesn't seem to give me what I want.  I'm good with utilizing PowerApps/Power Automate, but I'm just not sure what the best route to go is.  Essentially, I just want to display recent posts from a Teams Channel.

Thanks!!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is the built-in widget available on the Team site (modern UI)

Otherwise custom web-part can be developed utilizing GRAPH API